# What is the source of a wrong pointer value?

Tags: c, storage

EDIT: I know the second example is wrong and i know how to make it right, i want to know where does the wrong values came from and where do they point to when there is nothing? how does a became the value of `2686744`

Sry i dont know what answer i should choose at best so i gave all of you an upvote. maybe one will be choosen later.

When i create a pointer and try to grab it the wrong way like below:

```
int b = 5;
int *a;
a = &b;
```

As i understood, the right way to grab the value of the pointed variable a is

```
printf("value of a is: %d\n", *a);
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", *a);
```

then the output will be

```
value of a is: 5
storage location of a is: 00000005
```

but what does the output points to when i try it wrong like this?

```
printf("value of a is: %d\n", a);
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", a);
```

I get the output

```
value of a is: 2686744
storage location of a is: 0028FF18
```

Where does this came from? is there an automatic created storage location for a and where came the value from it?

i hope you understand me,, my english is not very good. thank you

Comment: `0028FF18` is `2686744` but in hex. `%p` is used for printing pointers only. `*a` dereferences the pointer and gives the value in the memory, pointed by `a`. `a` is the pointer itself and printing `a` will give you the address of `b`.

Comment: but 2686744 is not the storage location of b, and also not the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing format specifiers.

When you use `%d` in `printf`, the parameter you pass later should be `int`.
When you use `%p` the parameter you pass to it should be address.
Here:

```
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", *a);
```

You indicate `%p` but pass integer to it (value of object to which `a` points) which is wrong and undefined behaviour.

Same here:

```
printf("value of a is: %d\n", a);
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", a);
```

First is wrong. Second is correct actually, but you should use it like this:

```
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", (void*)a);
```

Comment: that means 2686744 is not a value, its a location?

Comment: @muni: Yes if you print value of `a` however with %p specifier you should get address of object to which a is pointing to. But you used %d to print value of `a` in that example, which is undefined behaviour

Comment: but doesnt a got the value of b by using `a = &b` ?

Comment: @muni: not sure what you mean. If you type: `printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", (void*)a);` This will give you *value* of a which is address of b - because a is pointing to b. Just you used wrong format specifier - %d - in the first example

Comment: ah ok, when i just output without `*` and let the compiler decide what to display, its always the given location, right?

Comment: @muni: if you have `int x = 5` and you output just x what will be output? The *value* of x right? which is 5. The *value* of pointer is *address* of object to which it points

Comment: @muni: when you do `*x` this is *value* of *object to which x points*. When you do just `x` this is just value of `x` (which in case of pointers is address as I said).

Comment: then its because an address is hexadecimal and i try to output a non hexadecimal value, but pass a hexadecimal storage location, right?

Comment: ok now im sure, i got it. http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter

Comment: @muni: *no just according to printf when you want to print address you should use %p and not %d*. (if address is number you can't say it is hexadecimal - it is just number - you can represent it in hex or other notation. e.g., if address is 13  you can write it like 0xD in hex or also in binary - they all have same value - but this is becoming now a separate discussion )

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is *dereferencing* the pointer `a`.

```
a = 0x0028FF18     // This is the virtual memory address of the variable b

printf("value of a is: %d\n", a);    // This prints it in decimal
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", a);  // This prints it in hex
```

What I believe you want is:

```
printf("value of a is: %d\n", *a);
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", a);
//                                       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", *a);
```

It should be:

```
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", a);
```

`a` is the memory address while `*a` is the indirection to get the value contained at that address.

Again here:

```
printf("value of a is: %d\n", a);
```

`a` is the address **not** the value - hence its UB to use the `%d` format specifier.

Comment: but 2686744 is not the location of a, 000005 is the location of a, or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", *a);
```

This is wrong as you are using the wrong format specifier to print out the `int` value

```
printf("storage location of a is: %p\n", (void *)a);
```

To get the value stored in this location have

```
printf("value of a is: %d\n", *a);
```

is the right way to print out the address in which the value is stored or what value the pointer is holding.

> Where does this came from? is there an automatic created storage
>   location for a and where came the value from it?

Nothing came from nowhere. You have a pointer pointing so some valid memory location and you are trying to print out the address as well as the the value stored in it and it should be done as shown above.

Comment: That means 2686744 is not a value, its a storage location?

Comment: @muni 0028FF18 is the pointer value/location to which your pointer is pointing/location in which the value `b=5` is stored. Yes the value of a is the address the value stored in the address is given by `*a` which is 5